# What is causing this "Cannot set property" error when trying to save to array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get the following error when trying to write to an array.

> TypeError: Cannot set property "1.0" of undefined to "xyz". (line 50, file "Code")

I am new to this and not sure how to fix.

#### Minimal reproducible example:

```
function iterateSheets() 
{
 var final_values = new Array(25000)
 final_values[0][1]  = "xyz";//error here
 }
```

Comment: Which line is line 50? Provide [mre]

Comment: line 50 =   final_values[x][0]  =consol_values[y][0];  //AI pack

Comment: I am guessing I am initializing the array wrong or something, I will think about minimizing but not sure how since most of the code is necessary to complete task.

Comment: `final_values[x]` will be undefined just like ``[][0]`` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You declared only the outer array of `final_values` as a array. But, You're trying to set a 2D array value.

#### Solution:

Declare the inner array as array too.

#### Snippet:

```
function iterateSheets() {
 var final_values = new Array(25000);
 final_values[0] = [];//Now final_values = [[],....]
 final_values[0][1]  = "xyz";//No error
 }
```

Comment: thank you for holding my hand on this one, I am new to this.

Comment: @data if that solves this error, you can accept this solution.